# Cannot delete Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have two Azure Active Directories that I cannot delete. One is a remnant from a project at a former company. One is from a Azure demo that I tried.

I am certain that these directories are not being used and I would naturally like to delete them.

When I switch to either of these directories I get a notification popup in the upper right corner of the Azure portal which states: "You do not have any Azure subscriptions in the  directory".

After switching to either of these directories I went to the Overview page (Azure Active Directory -> Overview).

In the menu bar at the top of the overview page the "Delete Directory" button is grayed out. Hence my problem.

Also the Overview page indicates that my role is User. Clearly this is not encouraging, since generally only owners can delete items.

So I appear to be stuck with this useless clutter.

Any suggestions. Should I contact Azure support and have them try?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Best regards,
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue as you (like 25 AD's from testing at different clients'), and no way to remove them. Contacting support will get this sorted quickly. I do wonder how people do this without a suppor package ;-)